# Android list Content-Resolver Uris

Tags: android-contentresolver

In android i can get a contentresolver with:

```
context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(
```

Is it possible to list all content-resolver-uris?

Answer (score 0):

The number of available content providers are based on what permissions you have specified in the Android Manifest for your application.

The Uri is made up of several parts. Are you trying to get all authorities or all possible paths for an authority?

You may see the current list of available content providers supplied by Android through [android.provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html)

Please see [Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#ContentURIs) for more information.